# How to use custom functions in QT4 for slots

Tags: c++

Currently I'm working on a class project where I'm making an asteroids game, and what I'm trying to figure out is how to use a custom function for a slot so when an Open QAction in a QMenu is clicked, that function is called. From what I understand, writing your own custom functions isn't possible, but is it possible to overload another function such as AboutQT to do what I want it to do? I am able to use the quit() function in there with this line for my Close QAction:

connect(closeSubAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

but I want to make one where quit() can be replaced by another function or make a predefined function do something different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `slots` keyword as seen in [this example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/signalsandslots.html#a-small-example).

Comment: Also note the `Q_OBJECT` macro - pretty sure that's essential, too.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is define a slot to which the QAction signal would be connected. See [Qt's documentation about signals and slots](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/signalsandslots.html).